# Application of a number not allowed (Scheme)

Tags: emacs, scheme, mit-scheme, sicm

I'm working a little with SCMUTILS package that implements MIT SCHEME. I'm running it from Emacs and I'm having trouble when using a function, can you help me?

My code is:

```
(define ((((delta eta) f) q) t)
  (let ((fmas (f (+ q (* 0.001 eta))))
         (efe (f q)))
       (/ (- (fmas t) (efe t)) 0.001)))


(define ((G q) t)
       (dot-product (q t) (q t)))


(((((delta  test-path) G)  test-path) 5))
```

Where test-path is:

```
(define (test-path t)
 (up (+ (* 4 t) 7)
     (+ (* 3 t) 5)
     (+ (* 2 t) 1)))
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Loading "mecanica"...
;Application of a number not allowed 2501.2500000000273 (())
```

what could be the problem?

At first I thought that scheme couldn't divide a structure like `test-path` by a number, so I put the dot product to make it a function that returns a number; but that didn't work.

I've tried printing expression in the `delta-eta` function and the error comes in while doing this part:

```
(/ (- (fmas t) (efe t)) 0.001)))
```

And if I take out the quotient part, there is no error.

Surely I am missing something. Hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: I can't get this running on it's own in my Scheme implementation. What's the definition of `up`, `efe`, `dot-product` and `fmas`? The error is simple. At some point you are doing `(some-var ...)` where `some-var` isn't resolved to a procedure but rather a number.

Comment: `test-path` is a function, but when you call `delta`, it gets assigned to the `eta` and `q` parameters, and then you add and multiply them.

Comment: I thought [scmutils](https://www.google.com/?q=scmutils) is a package that must be run inside MIT Scheme (not emacs) on Unix, as part of SICMechanichs book.

Comment: @Sylwester Sorry, the answer below shows the code clearer. Dot-product and up are procedures included with the SCMUtils package. It is a packaage designed to work with when using the book 'Structure and interpretation of Classical Mechanics'

Comment: @WillNess scmutils *can* be run from emacs. See my comments [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956349/error-running-scmutils-by-m-x-mechanics-in-emacs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume this

```
(define ((((delta eta) f) q) t)
  (let ((fmas (f (+ q (* 0.001 eta))))
         (efe (f q)))
       (/ (- (fmas t) (efe t)) 0.001)))
```

is equivalent to this

```
(define (delta eta)
  (lambda (f)
    (lambda (q)
      (lambda (t)
        (let ((fmas (f (+ q (* 0.001 eta))))
              (efe (f q)))
          (/ (- (fmas t) (efe t)) 0.001))))))
```

Then `(((((delta  test-path) G)  test-path) 5))` is multiplying `0.001` and `test-path` at `(* 0.001 eta)`. And also inside of the `G`, it expects `q` as a procedure however, `fmas` is retrieving a procedure from `G` passing a number to `G`. Thus this would try to apply calculated number passing `t`.