# how to programmatically call M-x functions in Edwin for MIT-Scheme?

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme, edwin

I'm using the Edwin editor with MIT-scheme, and because the default font size is so small, I do `M-x set-font` and then choose

```
-adobe-courier-bold-r-normal--24-240-75-75-m-150-iso8859-1
```

to make the font bigger. This works fine, but when I try to put

```
(set-font "-adobe-courier-bold-r-normal--24-240-75-75-m-150-iso8859-1")
```

in my `~/.edwin`, it complains about `Unbound variable: set-font`.

In emacs, interactive functions from `M-x` can usually be straightforwardly called programmatically in Elisp, but apparently not so here. I tried reading more about how to customize Edwin by looking at the manual with `info mit-scheme-user', but the Edwin chapter specifically says

> This manual does not discuss customization of Edwin.

How do I call `set-font` programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Edwin commands are not procedures, and cannot be called directly in Scheme code. However, a simple fix enables this, simply wrap it with the `ref-command` macro:

```
`((ref-command set-font) "-adobe-courier-bold-r-normal--24-240-75-75-m-150-iso8859-1")`
```

Source: [A 1997 mailing list thread with this exact same question](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.scheme/c/FF3ECWNOe90)

> Edwin commands aren't procedures (unlike GNU Emacs). An Edwin command
>   is a special object with an unusual name. If you want to invoke a
>   command from a program you must use the REF-COMMAND macro. For
>   example, to start a shell buffer as if you had typed "M-x shell": `((ref-command shell) #t)`