# Scmutils for SICM

Tags: scheme, sicp, mit-scheme, sicm

2 Edit: I found a solution.

1 Edit: I realaized that the description of my problem was pretty bad, so I state the problem anew, leaving the old question below.
I installed mit-scheme which works perfectly fine. While trying to get scmutils installed, following the steps [here](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/gjs/6946/linux-install.htm), I ran into the following problems:

1.
step 3 cannot be followed, since the web-page, where further instructions are supposed to be found, cannot be found.

2.
Step 5 asks to "Expand this gzipped tar archive by executing tar xzf scmutils-20190830.tar.gz". Typing that into the terminal gives:
"tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'scmutils-20190830.tar.gz.'"
, but I don't think that this step is really necessary, since I got a directory (Folder) named scmutils-20190830

3. At step 6 I am supposed to "execute the installation script install.sh.". After I clicked on install.sh a code in emacs popped up, which I copied to the terminal, giving me back:
   " zsh: no such file or directory: #/bin/bash
   dirname: illegal option -- z
   usage: dirname path
   find: Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Application Support/FileProvider: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Application Support/CallHistoryDB: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Autosave Information: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/IdentityServices: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Messages: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/HomeKit: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Sharing: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Mail: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Safari: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Suggestions: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Containers/com.apple.archiveutility: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Containers/com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Containers/com.apple.mail: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/PersonalizationPortrait: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Metadata/CoreSpotlight: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Metadata/com.apple.IntelligentSuggestions: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Cookies: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Caches/CloudKit: Operation not permitted
   find: Library/Caches/com.apple.ap.adprivacyd: Operation not permitted
   cp: Downloads/scmutils-20190830: No such file or directory

[Process completed]"

and then stops, seeming to run forever. So I guess the last step is the crucial one, which failed for some reason.
Since I would really like to get started with the book, I will be very grateful for any help.

Best regards,
Max

I read SICP during the last vacation and used both Mit-Scheme and DrRacket. Since I really enjoyed reading SICP and currently have a mechanics class, I figured it would be a good Idea to read SICM. Unfortunately I am having trouble to get Scmutils running. For your information I am not a CS-Student and am not too adept with using the terminal and stuff.

I downloaded Scmutils [here](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/gjs/6946/installation.html) and tried to follow the instructions. After running the `install.sh` code in the terminal, the computer tells me that the process is finished, but I can't enter anything in the terminal, even though I waited a couple of minutes (maybe not enough?).

When I enter `/usr/local/bin/mechanics`, I get: "no such file exists".

The answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956349/error-running-scmutils-by-m-x-mechanics-in-emacs) do not help me.

Entering: `sudo ./install.sh` gives me back `"command not found"`.

I would be very glad if anyone could help me! Thanks in advance !

Comment: You need to be a bit more clear about the error. What command did it fail to find? Do you have MIT/GNU Scheme installed?

Comment: you should use mit-scheme instead of racket.